# advise with RegEx validation in SP13 Nintex Form

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint-2013

Would somebody help with my RegEx validation, please. 
I am using Nintex Form in SharePoint 2013 and this is my current RegEx:

```
^[A-Z]{4}[.][0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{8}[.][0-9]{3}
```

this validates the input only if it's like: **PAGB.1234.12345678.123** 
Due to some changes, I also need to validate this **PAGB.12345.12.123**

Am I right to believe that this would achieve the above requirement:

```
^[A-Z]{4}[.][0-9]{4|5}[.][0-9]{2|8}[.][0-9]{3}
```

Please advise, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to use alternation or a range inside the limiting quantifier, and an end of string anchor `$`:

```
^[A-Z]{4}[.][0-9]{4,5}[.](?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{8})[.][0-9]{3}$
                  ^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%7B4%7D%5B.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%2C5%7D%5B.%5D%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C%5B0-9%5D%7B8%7D%29%5B.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=PAGB.1234.12345678.123%0D%0APAGB.12345.12.123&o=m)

Or a variation with an optional group (`[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{6})?` will match 2 digits, and then optionally another chunk of 6 digits):

```
^[A-Z]{4}[.][0-9]{4,5}[.][0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{6})?[.][0-9]{3}$
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the first case, you want to match either 4 or 5 digits, so a simple `{min,max}` variation of the limiting quantifier will do.

In the second case, you want to match either 2 or 8 digits, and `{2,8}` won't work since it will match 2, 3, 4 .. 8 digits. Only a grouping like `(?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{8})` or a variation with an optional group will work.